# Solution for the sequence of the number of "major flaps" in origami bases and its relation to other sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, origami

I have recently been getting into origami and reading Robert J. Lang's (a physicist and one of the leading modern origami artist) books. In the book *Origami Design Secrets* he showed a sequence of more and more complicated origami bases (the starting points for many origami creations).

[Here are the first 5 elements of the sequence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TypMv.png)

The basic unit in the base is the right isosceles triangle with two perpendicular folds in it, and you can see it tiled across the bases appearing $2^n$ times in the $n$-th element of the sequence.

Loosely speaking, the $n$-th base is created by tiling the $(n-2)$-th base 4 times in a square pattern. Lang claimed a correspondence between the circular arcs that can be drawn that span the previously described right isosceles triangles (shown in the image) and the number of major "flaps" to use in an origami creation. Each circle, partial or otherwise, corresponds to a flap.

The pattern goes 1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 13, 25 for the first few. I looked up this sequence on OEIS and found nothing, which was a novel experience for me. Does anybody have any ideas how to generalize this sequence and find a closed form solution? Does anybody see any relations to other sequences in geometry? Any help would be greatly appreciated!